# How to view location services settings in windows phone 7 emulator

Tags: windows-phone-7, emulation

I am new in Windows Phone 7,How to view location services settings in windows phone 7 emulator

Comment: @Adam: pls chk the link http://www.microsoft.com/windowsphone/en-us/howto/wp7/web/location-and-my-privacy.aspx

Comment: oh right, not quite the same then - asking if the location services are configured on or off?

Comment: yes adam.........im waiting for ur reply

Comment: I'd reply if I knew the answer, but I managed to misunderstand the question.  Now understanding the question I'm not sure how to change the emulator's settings.  On the surface it doesn't appear to be intuitive.

Comment: Do you know any updated version with location service settings?

Answer (score 1):

The default emulator image that is shipped with the development tools is not as full featured as the real OS.  You can't for example, setup email accounts, turn on airplane mode or edit location settings.  This does cause a problem when you wish to test your app without location services available or data connection, for example.  In the case of a data connection you can achieve this by turning off the network connection on your host operating system (Windows) but this is inconvenient.

An alternative is to install an unlocked ROM for the emulator.  You can, in fact, have multiple emulators installed which can be super convenient.  Check out Justin Angels blog post for more details.

http://justinangel.net/WindowsPhone7UnlockedRoms

Comment: Yes unlocked ROM having settings, but other than this we had any updated released version os for windows phone 7 with location service settings.